# listbox value with one row

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, listbox, scroll

I have a to select a number between one to thousand...

I dont want to use a dropdown list because there are too many values instead i want the box which has the values to act like a listbox with up and down arrows within the box...

I tried using the listbox with one row and it starts acting like a dropdownlist...

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" Rows="1">

            </asp:ListBox>
```

I am filling this listbox with from the codebehind..

any suggestions???

Comment: did u try to resize it to only show 1 row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use something like a numeric up-down control?   It requires AJAX but that might not be a problem.  There is a sample [here.](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/NumericUpDown/NumericUpDown.aspx)

Comment: the problem im facing with using the ajax kit is that im using a masterpage and dont know how to use ajax control with it.. can you help me with that. it will be quiet helpful.. thanks

Comment: There's no reason you can't use AJAX with master pages.  Have a look at http://www.asp.net/(S(sf10gzjodvrpce55el2p5cnk))/learn/master-pages/tutorial-08-cs.aspx for a tutorial.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet here is to use the Numeric Up/Down control that is part of the ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit.

Here is the [information/demo page](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/NumericUpDown/NumericUpDown.aspx) for it.

Answer (score 1):

Unless resizing the Listbox is not an Option you can try and resize it to show only 1 row, that would do the trick..

oh but remember to remove the rows="1" if you do that

**Edit: Added sample code, and added Div to show the horizontal Scroll bar**

```
  <Div style="Height:100px;Width:200px;Overflow:Auto">

<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" EnableTheming="True" 
    onselectedindexchanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged" Height="23px" Width="54px">
    <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>8</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>9</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
 </Div>
```

Comment: i did that but i dont get the scroll on the side... how do i get that..thanks

Comment: Enclose it with a div tag , that has a smaller height than it, and overflow = auto,, i edited my answer to have a sample code :)

Comment: this will not work because there is no scroll inside the list box but it has a scroll outside... i tried this.... also you have closed the div twice...but that i modified, so was not an issue..

Comment: fixed the doubled ending tag, and i dont get you.. if you add more than 1 item, the scroll bar shows automatically !

Comment: i just tested it, by adding the data from the code behind, and the listbox shows the scroll bar, and without the need for the div tags too!

Comment: Ok.. now this is a problem... are u using IE coz it works with that but try using firefox.. and you will understand what i mean...

Comment: ya i saw that with chrome... but now is there a way out or ajax is my last resort...

Answer (score 0):

It's called a SpinBox in WinForms. In ASP.NET, there are control vendors who have implemented this (like DevExpress) but you can also quite easily do it yourself, a bit like this (needs some formatting but that's up to you).